# I see incorrect photo when accessing Android via USB

Tags: usb, data-recovery, photos

I see incorrect photo when accessing Android via USB. It's different from the one, I see in telephone itself. If I copy this photo to desktop, I get wrong image. If I move photo to desktop, I loose data.

This completely compromises USB access to Android.

Is it possible to avoid such situations by 100%?

Comment: There is a known bug in Media Transfer Protocol (MTP) in combination with Windows 10 that can lead to data loss. It is known since mid 2017, may be your device is affected. Regarding the files the easiest workaround is to reboot your phone.

Comment: Didn't know about this - MTP is a complete disaster of a protocol. I don't know why more phones don't just display as mass storage.